# how to output data into new files g1 g2 g3 for each sorting method in c language

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, file-io

how to output data into new files g1 g2 g3 for each sorting method in c language

This is the code that i have done .. Might be a little messy but i somehow managed to make it work i think. I was wondering how to separately print the sorting output in each of their different files. Any advice or suggestions on how to do it will be appreciated

edit: i dont know if the program works because the plan was to run the loop till the array size (which will be the total values in the file) but i didnt know how to run a loop through an array without knowing its size in c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>


void getRandomArray(int arr[], int n, int max); //initiate an array with random numbers
void cloneArray(int arrB[], int arrA[], int size); //copy an array to another
void printArray(int arr[], int size); //print all elements of an array
void swap(int *xp, int *yp);
void selectionSort(int arr[], int n); //selection sort
void insertionSort(int list[], int n); //insertion sort

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

 FILE *myFile;
    myFile = fopen("test_dat.txt", "r");

    //read file into array
   
    int i;
    int SIZE=10000;
    int arrA[SIZE], arrB[SIZE];      
    if (myFile == NULL){
        printf("Error Reading File\n");
        exit (0);
    }

    for (i = 0; i <SIZE; i++){
        fscanf(myFile, "%d,", &arrA[i] );
    }

    cloneArray( arrB, arrA, SIZE);
    printArray(arrA, SIZE);

    clock_t start = clock();

    cloneArray(arrB, arrA, SIZE);
    start = clock();
    selectionSort(arrB, SIZE);
    printf("Time = %f ms\n", 1000.0*(clock()-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    printArray(arrB, SIZE);

    cloneArray(arrB, arrA, SIZE);
    start = clock();
    insertionSort(arrB, SIZE);
    printf("Time = %f ms\n", 1000.0*(clock()-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    printArray(arrB, SIZE);
    
    free(arrA);
    free(arrB);
    
fclose(myFile);
}


//=======================================================

void cloneArray(int arrB[], int arrA[], int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        arrB[i] = arrA[i];
}

void printArray(int arr[], int size) {
    for (int i=0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

void swap(int *xp, int *yp) {
    int temp = *xp;
    *xp = *yp;
    *yp = temp;
}

//=======================================================

void selectionSort(int arr[], int n) {
    puts("\n==================== Selection Sort ==================== ");
    int comp = 0, swp = 0;
    int min_idx;
    for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
        min_idx = i;
        for (int j = i+1; j < n; j++)
            if (arr[j] < arr[min_idx]) {
                min_idx = j;
                comp++;
            }
        swap(&arr[min_idx], &arr[i]);
        swp++;
    }
    printf("No. comparisons = %d; No. swaps = %d\n", comp, swp);
}

void insertionSort(int list[], int n) {
    puts("\n==================== Insertion Sort ====================");
    int comp = 0, assg = 0;
    for (int h = 1; h < n; h++) {
        int key = list[h];
        int k = h - 1; //start comparing with previous item
        while (k >= 0 && key < list[k]) {
            list[k + 1] = list[k];
            comp++;
            assg++;
            --k;
        }
        list[k + 1] = key;
    }
    printf("No. comparisons = %d; No. assignments = %d\n", comp, assg);
      
    return 0;
} //end insertionSort
```

Comment: Open a different file in each function and write to it?  It's not clear what specific difficulty you have.

Comment: Well i wanted to pass file function through the print method but i didnt know how to pass it but now i resolved everything on my own. 

The question i asked before is how to write to different files but yeah i just understood the logic on how to do that so done